# Bootstrap core javascript suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I'm a beginner here, and currently developing a web application. My situation is for few months i had using this Bootstrap core javascript source and suddenly today the console shows error which I completely dont know how to solve it and it is affecting and messing up my web application page.

**This is the Bootstrap js source that i'm using**

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**This is the image of the error from the web console**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem above is solved by inserting new links for the CSS and JS of bootstrap latest update. You can refer [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) for the guide on using latest bootstrap 4.